# Move matched text to the end of string using Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
hello bye!
goodbye again.
```

I am hoping to move any occurrences of `bye` in the text above to the end. I am not sure if it could be done by regex in Javascript.

I expect the output text to be:

```
hello !
good again.
bye
bye
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **replace** and **join**

- First replace the matching word by empty string
- In callback of replace function push the values to an array and return empty string from it.
- In the end join replaced string and array element by `\n`

```js
let str = `hello bye!
goodbye again.`

let replacer = (str) => {
  let temp = []
  let strTemp = str.replace(/bye/g, match => {
    temp.push(match)
    return ''
  })
  return [strTemp, ...temp].join('\n')
}

console.log(replacer(str))
```